# Limit of expectation over gaussians with vanishing variance (or just a limit of integrals)

Tags: integration, limits

In a probability-related problem, I am interested in the average of the following function $f(x,y) = y^2\tanh^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-t}}{t}x y\right)$ with respect to the following family multi-variate Gaussian distributions:

\begin{align}
p_{t}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t}(y-\sqrt{1-t}~ x)^2}
\end{align}

In particular, I need to understand the behaviour of this average for $t\to 0$:
$$
\lim\limits_{t\to 0^{+}}\mathbb{E}_{p_{t}}f(x,y) = \lim\limits_{t\to 0^{+}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t}(y-\sqrt{1-t}~ x)^2}y^2\tanh^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-t}}{t}x y\right)
$$
**bonus**: can we also get the subleading behaviour?

---

**Attempt**:

A naif approach was to invert the average and the limit (which of course is *not* justified here, since the probability measure is also a function of $t$): since as $t\to 0^{+}$ we have $\tanh^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-t}}{t}x y\right)\to 1$, the first integral gives $x^2(1-t)+t$. The limit is thus $x^2$ which would give a result of $1$. One would get the same by arguing that the whole measure over $y$ goes to $\delta(y-x)$ as $t\to 0^{+}$ together with $\tanh^2 \to 1$ and then integrating.

However, when I numerically plot this integral as a function of $t$, I get a curve that continuously approach $1$ at $t=0$, but rapidly drops to $0$ in a small neighbourhood of $t=0$. This confused me and motivated me searching for a *rigorous* argument.